# Sending email fails with `Process smtpmail not running`

Tags: mu4e

I followed [this guide](http://cachestocaches.com/2017/3/complete-guide-email-emacs-using-mu-and-/) to set up IMAP email with Emacs, `mu`, and `mu4e`. I can pull email and view it in `mu4e` alright, but I can't seem to send email. I press `C` for Compose, edit the email, then `C-c C-c` to send, and I get `Process smtpmail not running` in the mini-buffer window.

My SMTP configuration in `~/.emacs` is:

```
(setq
 message-send-mail-function   'smtpmail-send-it
 user-mail-address "name@domain.tld"
 smtpmail-default-smtp-server "smtp.office365.com"
 smtpmail-smtp-server         "smtp.office365.com"
 smtp-mail-service 587
 smtpmail-local-domain        "name@domain.tld")
```

I haven't found any pointers to this problem. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: perhaps : `message-send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it`  ?

Comment: Isn't that the second line of my code?

Comment: it is... you are right . what about a `smtpmail-stream-type` value 'starttls or other?

Comment: That does work, yes! It prompts me for username and password and I get `Sending failed: ... Authentication unsuccessful [domain.domain.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM] in response to [random characters]`. I tried setting `(setq smtpmail-auth-credentials '(("smtp.office365.com" 25 "username@domain.com" "password")))` as in this EmacsWiki and it still prompts me for the password. It does the same with 587 instead of 25. How can I set the credentials?

Comment: That should be in your .offlineimaprc file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the IMAP settings of the email provider. Office365, for example, has these settings under Settings > Your app settings > Mail > Mail > Accounts > POP and IMAP:

> ## SMTP setting
>
> Server name: smtp.office365.com
>
> Port: 587
>
> Encryption method: STARTTLS

Therefore, adding this line in your `~/.emacs` should work:

```
(setq smtpmail-stream-type 'starttls)
```

You need to specify your credentials for SMTP in addition to those for IMAP (which would be in `~/.offlineimaprc`, for example). You can give your credentials in the mini-buffer during the first authentication, or you can save this text in `~/.authinfo`:

```
machine smtp.office365.com login username@domain.com port 587 password XYZ
```

You can use port 587 (TLS, secure), or port 25 (no TLS, non-secure). If you use 587, you need to also set the auth-source lookup to that value:

```
(setq smtpmail-smtp-service 587)
```

For password protection look at `.netrc` , or `GPG`.

**Update from OP**: in a previous version, I used port 25 (SMTP without TLS) in `~/.authinfo`, else I was prompted with `SMTP user name for smtp.office365.com (default email):`. Thanks to @rpluim for the setting of `smtpmail-smtp-service` in a comment to @Cenderme's answer.

Comment: That's not the way SMTP AUTH works: you authenticate and send using the same port, in this case 587. (Direct TLS to port 465 would be even better, but maybe Office365 doesn't support that).

Comment: I tried with 465 both for `smtpmail-smtp-service` and on `.authinfo` and it fails, despite the company (which is now different from Microsoft) having a page with `"Server: mail.secure.aluminati.net (Port: 587, if that fails try 465)"`. Is there a different setting for 465, and why is 465 better?

Answer (score 1):

Add these into your init file (e.g. `~/.emacs`):

```
(setq
 user-mail-address "email@hotmail.com"
 message-send-mail-function   'smtpmail-send-it
 smtpmail-smtp-service 587
 smtpmail-smtp-server         "smtp.office365.com"
 smtpmail-stream-type 'starttls
 ;;smtpmail-auth-credentials '(expand-file-name "~/.authinfo.gpg") Please read the update and comments.
)
```

I use spacemacs, so you might want to change these lines. Rearrange your `~/.authinfo` file as in

```
machine smtp.office365.com login email@hotmail.com port 587 password "pass"
machine outlook.office365.com login "email" port 993 password "pass"
```

Also, type this into terminal

```
gpg -c .authinfo
```

This protects your files with GPG. It will ask for a password, just enter anything.

**Update from OP**: @rpluim suggested that this code is redundant: `(setq smtpmail-starttls-credentials '(("smtp.office365.com" 587 nil nil)))` because `smtpmail-starttls-credentials` was removed 8 years ago. @rpluim also suggested setting `smtpmail-smtp-service` to 587 to coincide with the port in `~/.authinfo`. Both changes work in sending mail.

Comment: Good answer that includes GPG and password file encryption.

Comment: Do you use the same password file for retrieving and sending mail? Can you point me to Emacs settings to configure credentials for POP3?

Comment: With port `587` in the `~/.authinfo` first line for SMTP, I get prompted: `SMTP user name for smtp.office365.com (default email):` and then `SMTP password for email@smtp.office365.com:`. I solved it by replacing port 587 with port 25 but I understand from @rpluim's comment above that it's not how SMTP AUTH works. Do you have an idea or should I ask a separate question?

Comment: Which version of emacs are you using? `smtpmail-starttls-credentials` was removed 8 years ago. The reason you're getting prompted is because the default value of `smtpmail-smtp-service` is 25, which means the auth-source lookup is being done with that value. Set it to 587, and have 587 in your .authinfo, and it should all work.

Comment: I was using Emacs 26.3. I confirm that your changes work and updated the answer. Thanks for the help on 587 versus 25, I now have a more secure SMTP setup.