# authinfo.gpg but still promted for smtpmail credentials

Tags: mu4e, smtpmail, authinfo

I have the following in my init.el:

```
(require 'smtpmail)
(setq message-send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it
     smtpmail-stream-type 'starttls
     smtpmail-default-smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com"
     smtpmail-auth-credentials (expand-file-name "~/.authinfo.gpg")
     smtpmail-smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com"
     smtpmail-smtp-service 587)
```

.authinfo decrypts fine and contains:

```
machine smtp.gmail.com login ***1 password ***2 port 465
```

Where ***1 and ***2 are my username and password respectively.

But upon sending mail from mu4e I am still prompted for credentials.

If I enter the credentials at the prompt sending works.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `auth-source` lookup done by smtpmail uses the `smtpmail-smtp-service` port as well, so you need to specify '587' in .authinfo.gpg (although personally I advocate for using port 465 and a stream-type of 'tls).

Comment: Thank you very much. Why do you recommend tls/465 and will that work with the gmail servers?

Comment: Yes it works with gmail. The reason I recommend it is that when using direct tls, your connection is always encrypted. When using 587/starttls, the connection starts out unencrypted and is then 'upgraded' to encrypted, which leaves a window for your connection to be read, or even for the upgrading to be disabled (by filtering out the announcement of STARTTLS capability from the remote server).

Comment: Great feedback, thanks.

Comment: [This thread](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/46257/sending-email-fails-with-process-smtpmail-not-running?noredirect=1#comment71150_46257) suggests using port 25, which I understand is for establishing the session keys. Both ports 465 and 587 prompt me for my password. Do you not get prompted for a password when using ports 465 and 587?

Comment: There is no establishment of 'session keys' with SMTP. You connect to a port, using either TCP or TLS, and the remote server can then choose to prompt you for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and I had consistent port numbers.
It seems `smtpmail-auth-credentials` is no longer needed (since Emacs 24.1).
Keeping the information in `~/.authinfo.gpg` and removing the line from your init file will work. (Based on xuchunyang's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25941628/what-is-the-correct-way-to-set-the-variable-smtpmail-auth-credentials))